# Returning only number of tests passed and number of tests failed

Tags: python, pytest

When using `pytest`, I'd like to output only the number of tests passed and the number of tests failed.

If I call `pytest` on my test file, collect 10 tests, and pass all of them, I'd like to output `10,0`.

If I call `pytest` on my test file, collect 10 tests, and pass all but 2, I'd like to output `8,2`.

Is there a way to do this, even if it is outside `purest`?  I imagine it requires some clever regex, which is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with a simple oneliner in `bash`, e.g.

```
$ pytest -v | tee >(grep FAILED | wc -l) >(grep PASSED | wc -l) >/dev/null | paste -sd "," -
```

Or you can implement a small plugin that does the counting:

```
# conftest.py

@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.pluginmanager.register(MyPlugin(), 'my_plugin')


class MyPlugin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.passed = 0
        self.failed = 0

    def pytest_runtest_logreport(self, report):
        if report.when != 'call':
            return
        if report.passed:
            self.passed += 1
        elif report.failed:
            self.failed += 1

    def pytest_sessionfinish(self, session, exitstatus):
        print(self.passed, self.failed, sep=',')
```

When running with the `terminal` plugin turned off, this plugin yields the desired output:

```
$ pytest -p no:terminal
23,2
```